# Feature request for accepting grammar and punctuation edits one at a time

Tags: feature-request

It would be helpful when another user makes edits to a post to be able to accept them individually. I have found that sometimes people will remove things like 'Update:' or make changes that skew the authors intent in addition to perfectly valid changes.

Comment: If the whole edit isn't good, reject it and apply the good bits yourself.

Comment: That is perfect in a world where people have lots of time.

Comment: Surely that would take less time than cherry picking? And it would encourage people to make wholly-good edits.

Comment: Update: / Edit: and the like should not be in a post. It might be more difficult than just removing those markers to correct things though...

Comment: Not in the 2 cases I am referencing. 8 down votes in 14 views? I guess its a bad idea? I guess I will default to my default behavior: 'since I do not have enough time to do this correct I will not accept any changes.'

Comment: But... you only have 300 rep, so you can't review suggested edits...

Comment: @TinyGiant OP can accept edits to they own posts so. I've seen people restoring "thank you"/"give me code now urgently" text after edits. Trying to educate (as Deduplicator tried) in such cases is rarely useful effort.

Comment: @Alexei Ah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

I get the feeling that this is more about your posts in particular than about the site in general.

Looking at your past few posts, frankly, they're quite unreadable. Run-on sentences, no proper capitalization of brand names, inline numbered listings and irrelevant markup like "Update" and "<--".

Editors tend to fix that, so your post becomes more readable. You should not roll back capitalization edits *"because I don't like iphones"*.

From [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.